# Ruby On Rails Error explanation SASS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sass

I am learning rails (railstutorial.org v5 by Hartl) and i have problem with listing 7.22 chapter 7 Here its my repository https://github.com/xt442/railstutorialorg I should have this message 
[image]

I have something like that. The content is not red 
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your custom.scss stylesheet

you have one extra } at the end (line 170)

this extra bracket should be on line 109, to close the footer styles.

you've basically wrapped all your styles under footer in error.

(fyi, cloned and tested locally and working for me)